# Get bootstrap button toggle state right after click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, toggle, jquery-events

I'm using twitter-bootstrap and want to evaluate the toggle button states right after clicking.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {...});
```

works basically but returns only the old state of the buttons. How do I get the latest visible state of the buttons evaluated in Javascript? I read a discussion here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2380 but didn't see a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution and hence answer to myself:

```
($("[type='checkbox']").find(':checked'), function(){...})
```

works immediately and solves the issue for me.